# Method for side effects in Optional<T>?

Tags: java

I'm searching for a way to perform a task that may do side effects.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

```
getOptionalHumanObject()
    .map((Human h1) -> human::getName)
    .do((String name) -> System.out::printLn)
    .do((String name) -> invokeImportentHttpPostRequest(x))
    .map((String name) -> name.length())
    ...
```

For now the only way I thought is using filter/map, do my side effect and return true/same object.

Does Optional class methods are not intend to use for side effects before a terminal operation like ifPresent?

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit for Stack Overflow: you are not asking about software engineering concepts or design issues, but about how to use a specific class in a specific programming language. If you ask there, please delete this question (do not cross post). It might also be helpful to add a small code snippet to illustrate what you are trying to do, e.g. I don't know what Rx is.

Comment: @amon: I'm assuming he means [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), though `Optional<T>` appears to be merely a variation on the `Maybe` monad.  Neither has much to do with side-effects, which would be an anti-pattern in either context.

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey, Why would it be an anti-pattern in the contect of Optional<T> class?

Comment: Because Maybe monads are a *functional programming* construct.  Functional programming (of the sort that most programmers are familiar with) assumes immutability by default.

Comment: Hi @amon, After reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68384/whats-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-se, its a 75- 25 chance that my question will be off-topic over there. I expanded as you recommended my question hopefully more people give their opinions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You can employ some functional programming concepts without necessarily fully indoctrinating yourself into its cult.

Comment: @Alexander: You can, of course, do anything you want.  But a reasonable person looking at a Maybe monad would expect the other principles of functional programming to apply as well.  Why would you attempt to drive your car to work with only three wheels installed?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's not at all true. You're still dealing with an imperative language with eager evaluation, almost no support immutability enforcement, and many other short comings that make it garbage for functional programming. Our goal isn't to circle jerk around functional principles (which I love, don't get me wrong), but at some point or another you have to realize you're trying to retrofit rockets on a horse and carriage. You have to draw the line somewhere. Having a print side effect fall in the realm of the perfectly reasonable, imo.

Comment: @Alexander: Like I said, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a general conversion of any `Consumer<T>` to the identity function with a side effect:

```
public final class MyFunctions {
  public static <T> Function<T, T> doing(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    return t -> { consumer.accept(t); return t; };
  }
  // more here
}
```

With a static import, you can then use this facility with `Optional.map` as follows:

```
getOptionalHumanObject()
  .map(Human::getName)
  .map(doing(System.out::println))
  .map(doing(name -> invokeImportantHttpPostRequest(x)))
  .map(String::length);
```

Comment: I would call it `peek`, just like the `Stream` method.

Answer (score 4):

Why not combine all your operations into a single lambda invoked via `ifPresent`?

```
getOptionalHumanObject()
    .map((Human h1) -> human::getName)
    .ifPresent((String name) -> {
        System.out.printLn(name)
        invokeImportentHttpPostRequest(x)
     });
```

Comment: To the OP (I don't want this comment to be lost in the discussion from Software Engineering): there is a difference between `ifPresent` and `isPresent`.  The former will take in a method and run it with the value if it is present.  The latter simply tells you whether the value is present or not.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, I want to keep the chain of operations after calling to invokeImportentHttpPostRequest(x). I guess the intention for this class is to not do any side effects..

Comment: @StavAlfi I dont understand. Give me a better description of exactly what youre trying to do

Comment: @Alexander as `ifPresent` returns a `void`, you need to indent one additional level each time you add a side effect which gets ugly really quickly.

Comment: @Wouter I'm not sure what you're trying to say

Comment: @Alexander if you need additional functional operations, the following way would be nicest, but isn't possible:
`.ifPresent((String name) -> {
        System.out.printLn(name)
        invokeImportentHttpPostRequest(x)
     }).map(...).filter(...)...`
instead you need to write everything afterwards within the `ifPresent` (and need an additional `ifPresent` when adding another side effect later on).
Also, imagine you want to return your result `return getOptionalHumanObject().map.ifPresent(...)` this wouldn't be possible anymore.

Comment: @Wouter I don't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica could you elaborate on what part is unclear to you?

The best use-case I can think of to illustrate what I'm trying to say is "what if invokeImportentHttpPostRequest has a return value that you want to map"

Comment: @Wouter Reread the whole thread, and I think I got it now. `ifPresent` is a terminal operation, returning `void`. I think what you're looking for is more akin to Ruby's [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) method. It takes a lambda (called a block in ruby), calling it with `this` (called `self` in Ruby) as the sole parameter, and then returning `this` for further method chaining. This feature is generalization to any method chain on any kind of object, not just `Optional<T>`. If it were to exist, I think it should be added to `Object`.